# mkdir -p command for network folder missing something

Tags: mkdir

I'm not very good at using the command line or applescript. I found the following but something is missing
It creates the folder on my computer, not the server. Please help me understand what quotes or
lines I have in the wrong place.( sorry I do not know the lingo)

the new folder I want to create is a variable $ID (ex IN19535) it represents a students record
The server is mounted successfully  prior to running this shell script through applescript and a calculated field in FMP 11

I want to make the folder $ID in the StudentRecords folder.

```
do shell script \"mkdir -p \" & quoted form of \"/Volumes/Departments/StudentRecords/" & $ID & "\"
```

Thank you for your help, I am extremely frustrated.

Comment: so you want to create a directory in the StudentRecords folder that will have the name of whatever $ID contains?  Have you tried this:  `mkdir -p "/Volumes/Departments/StudentRecords/$ID"`

Comment: Yes it remains as $ID, doesn't populate the field with the information I also receive and error " Expected string but found end of script" when I run it.

Comment: And what operating system is this, to be exact?